# How to send email from localhost without synchronizing with external SMTP server?

Tags: php, email

I remember when I was in the college, my lab lecturer taught me how to create a desktop application that can send email using SMPT. I don't need to setup any email server for it.

Now I want to send email from my PHP webpage using inbuilt PHP function mail() but I can't seems get the code to work. I look at the internet and found that many of the solution needs external (or XAMPP internal) mail server, like google mail server or mercury. But I don't want to use that. I just want to send email from localhost for testing purpose. I need to be able to craft custom `FROM` email address field. I don't need to receive email replies back.

Can you teach me how to setup my localhost setting to do that? Up until now, I haven't do any modification at all to the php.ini regarding the mail settings.

My code to send email is (more or less):

```
$from = "admin@somecompany.com";
$subject = "Login Information";

$message = 
"<html><head>
<title>Your Login Information</title>
<style>body { font-family: Arial, 'Sans Serif'; }</style>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello ".$row['name'].",<p>
<p>This is your login information:</p>
<p>Email: ".$row['email']."<br/>
Password ".$row['password']."</p>
<p>Please login <a href='http://example.com/login.php'>here</a> using that information.<br> 
This is an automated email send. Do not reply this email. Thank you.</p>
<br/><br/><br/>
<p>Website Administrator</p>
</body></html>";

$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
mail($email,$subject,$message,'From: $from\n');
```

I want to be able to send email even though the `FROM` field email address is from `admin@somecompany.com` or even `admin@example.com`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use PHP Pear:

Installation (on Ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo pear install mail
sudo pear install Net_SMTP
sudo pear install Auth_SASL
sudo pear install mail_mime
```

Usage:

```
<?php
include('Mail.php');

$recipients = 'joe@example.com';

$headers['From']    = 'richard@example.com';
$headers['To']      = 'joe@example.com';
$headers['Subject'] = 'Test message';

$body = 'Test message';

$params['sendmail_path'] = '/usr/lib/sendmail';

// Create the mail object using the Mail::factory method
$mail_object =& Mail::factory('sendmail', $params);

$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $body);
?>
```

Comment: Sorry I haven't put information that I run XAMPP under windows. But you've opened my eyes to the PEAR library. I never knew there is a repository like this! Thanks!

Comment: a quick question: under windows, what is the path for 'sendmail_path'? My PHP installation is in `I:\XAMPP\PHP`. Thanks.

Comment: Glad do see you've got everything you need.  I'm not too sure when it comes to Windows, I run GNU/Linux on all my machines.